# How to specify path when doing git show on a merge commit

Tags: git, merge, git-show

I've got a merge commit, and I can show the entirety of it using `git show -m`. However, if I want to only show the change for a subfolder or a path, how do I do it? I tried doing `git show -m -- app/` but it didn't show anything, even though `git show --stat` indicates that there were merges going on in that part of the repository.

Comment: `git show -m app/` *should* work, as `-m` should override the usual combined-diff issues.  You may still get two (or more) diffs from this since `git show -m` actually runs two (or more) diff commands internally, one for each parent.  You can also do `git diff commit^ commit -- app/` and `git diff commit^2 commit -- app/` to diff parent#1 vs commit, or parent#2 vs commit.

Comment: @torek I actually typed `git show -m -- app/` (sorry), though doing `git show -m app/` gave the same results.

Comment: Oh, actually, I'm wrong: `git show -m -- app/` fails because (apparently) `git show` does not handle `git diff` style path limiting at all.  You'll have to resort to the `git diff` commands, or use `--relative` as krzyk answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `--relative` for that:

```
git show -m --relative=app/
```

But it will show paths relative to the directory provided in the path:

> `--relative[=<path>]`
>
> When run from a subdirectory of the project, it can be told to exclude changes outside the directory and show pathnames relative to it with this option. When you are not in a subdirectory (e.g. in a bare repository), you can name which subdirectory to make the output relative to by giving a `<path>` as an argument.